# Activate journey after DE get new records

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, dataextensions, event, entry-criteria

How can I activatee a journey each time my DE has new records? I already built something like this using the schedule time, but on this time I will need the run the journey immediatly each time my DE have a new record. All the option I found I need to configure this at least hourly.

Comment: How is your DE getting new records? SQL? CloudPage Form?

Comment: Hi iManage, I field this DE using a LadingPage.

Answer (score 1):

Create the Smart Capture form in CloudPages before creating this entry event:

To admit contacts into a journey, use Smart Capture forms created with Classic Content.

Give each Smart Capture form a name so it is selectable when defining your entry event.

Use a Smart Capture form with only one active journey at a time.

Drag Event onto the canvas.

Click Event.

Choose CloudPages Form Submit Event.

On the Select Event Source page, click the Smart Capture form that this event uses. When a customer submits the Smart Capture form, that customer is automatically added to a data extension and queued to enter this journey.

Click Next.

After building the journey, click Activate to begin admitting contacts who submit the designated Smart Capture form.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation iManage, but for my case I'm not use the lading page to get some answers from the client. I should explained all my workflow first I'm sorry. But I will send an email and on it I will have a link..when someone click on the link first I will redirect him for my ladingpage(in blank) once it I capture who click on the link and send this information for a DE.  So the ideia is, each time that link is linked I grab the information send to a DE and then I need to run the journey for it send another email

Comment: If I'm not mistaken you would have to work with the API and a custom entry event to achieve this realtime. Would be interested to know myself if there is an easier way without heavy coding.